# Cross platform File Transfer via wifi connection

Tags: windows, linux, wifi

Is there any software to transfer Files between different machines that have Linux/Windows as OS , using an active WIFI connection?

Comment: Are you looking for some clinet/server architecture or peer-to-peer?

Comment: Could you specify which linux you use? Some have build-in capabilities (like the ones described in Steves answer), some have not.

Comment: @AngeloFuchs Arch linux with bspwm as window manager. I am afraid I don't have a Desktop Environment :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a network shared directory on each machine you can just drag and drop into it with file explorer/dolphin/etc., once the shared folder is mounted regardless of the type of network connection, (just the speed changes).

No additional software needed - you may have to also do some network settings of the connection types in windows, (home or office **not** public).

Comment: I have previously tried using homegroup b/w windows machines , and that works. Currently I have arch with no DE and rather a Window Manager so that might be difficult. Could you please provide a little insight about how could I achieve it b/w Windows and Linux :)

Comment: http://www.7tutorials.com/how-access-windows-7-shared-folders-ubuntu & http://www.7tutorials.com/how-access-ubuntu-shared-folders-windows-7 or http://www.7tutorials.com/accessing-shared-partitions-ubuntu-windows-7

Comment: That is why I need another application to do all these work by itself. These links might be enough for setting up ubuntu and windows7 , but as distro's change around ( believe me , in my class you'll see over 10-15 types of them ) , setting them becomes time consuming. Anyways thanks for these links , I'm going to accept this as answer.

Comment: @AbhinavGauniyal - Once you have grasped the various ways of working you will find that you can cope with changes - _esp. on the Linux side as fundamentals tend to be stable_ - but if you rely on an App when it stops working due to say a win upgrade you have to wait for the authors to fix it.